# Replace PHP DOM Element

Tags: php

I want to replace third table in php dom object with a new table. I can select it by

```
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(3);
```

I tried

```
$table->parentNode->appendChild($new_table);
```

and it says

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 73
```

Can someone please explain what is wrong with the code or how I can correct it?

```
$new_table = "<table width='100%' bgcolor='#000'>$table_rows</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by extracting the idea from answers below and some more research.

```
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(3);
$new_table = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$new_table->appendXML("<table width='100%' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>$table_rows</table>");
$table->parentNode->replaceChild($new_table,$table);
```

The actual problem was with my $table_rows array that each row contained some extra attributes like "colspan", $nbsp; and some additional tags.

Thank you guys for your interest and support.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [createElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) to create the table fragment before appending it.

You could also create a fragment from the XML using [appendXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php) and then append that fragment using `appendChild`

```
$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML("<table width='100%' bgcolor='#000'>$table_rows</table>");
// now append the fragment
$table->parentNode->appendChild($fragment);
```

Here's a working example: http://ideone.com/0Lx742

Comment: it says: Warning: DOMNode::appendChild(): Document Fragment is empty `$table->parentNode->appendChild($fragment);`

Comment: Not sure what else you're doing wrong but here's a working example: http://ideone.com/0Lx742

Comment: @Azee Care to share? What turned out to be the problem?

Comment: Sure thing :) I just removed extra attributes from each row in $table_rows array for example "colspan" and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Miky's answer is step 1: you must construct your element as a DOM node.

```
$new_table = $dom->createElement("table");
$new_table->setAttribute("width","100%");
$new_table->setAttribute("bgcolor","#000");
foreach($table_rows as $row) $new_table->appendChild($row);
// the above assumes $table_rows is an array of TR nodes, not strings!
```

Step 2 is:

```
$table->parentNode->replaceChild($new_table,$table);
```

Comment: Can't I just append html from string instead of creating table and rows?

Comment: No. Well... I suppose you *could* create another document, use `loadHTML`, then import the root node into the first document...

Comment: Yeah it makes sense but this approach will not work in my scenario. Let me tell you, I am just reading an html email ($message) that contains a table of products. In order to sort product's order in the table I am reading table rows into an array, sorting the array and recreating the table and appending it back to $message dom object. Am I following the right track?